# Function gets null value from one of the parameters from ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send 2 parameters with data: using ajax. One of the params is a string, and that one always comes out on the c# side as it should, but the second parameter that is an object that consists of few strings and ints, always comes empty to the function.

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "/Clients/Create",
        data: { client : client, country : country},
        method : "post"
    });
```

The interesting part is that when debugging the js file from browser, the debugger says that the objects contain all they should.

```
    public void Create(Client client, string country)
    {
       //creates...
    }
```

Country param comes out right, but all of the clients values are either null or 0. I tried swapping their places to see if it has something to do with order, no luck there. Also I tried multiple ways to do "data: { client : client, country : country},".

Client class:

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Client() { }
}
```

This is how I'm building the object of a client in js.

```
var client = {
    Name : name,
    Address : address,
    City : city,
    Zip : zip
}
```

Comment: How does your `Client` looks like ? What specific data is not coming ?

Comment: What is inside the `client` variable ? how are you building it ?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to post this code in the comments, sry, I will edit it in question I guess

Comment: @Shyju There, posted all in question update.

Comment: Do you have valid value for `name` variable in js ? That code should work.

Comment: Yes, the debugger shows that everything is right on js side, I'm debugging it with chrome.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using ? This should work in an MVC5 app

Comment: It needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ client : client, country : country}),` and you need to include `contentType: 'application/json'`

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you if Client is a mvc model

```
var client = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(yourModelClient))');
car country = "country";  
var dataPlus = {
                 client : JSON.stringify(client),                   
                 country: country
            };
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Client")',
    data:   dataPlus,
    method : "POST",
});
```

then controller

```
[HttpPost]
public actionresult Create(Client client, string country)
{

}
```

Comment: It is not an mvc model, I'm gathering data to make a client. Although I tried something similar to the suggested solution. I did JSON.stringify(client) and put it in the equivalent of your dataPlus. Again, only the country went through, client keeps being empty.

Comment: have you try to json.stringify your gathering data but var by var something like    JSON.stringify({
                            'var': foo,
                            'var2': foo,  }),

Comment: Yes, that was one of the solutions that was posted here, but there was no luck.

Comment: traditional: true, option of ajax ? with just the client ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Sending just the client works fine, but trying to send 2 objects where one or more are complex, seems like impossible.

Comment: try  ajax =>  data : $.param(dataplus)